# android sys rtc wakealarm does not boot device when off

Tags: android

i have a galaxy tab 3 tab t210r and galaxy tab 2 p3113. the t210r is a stock rom. the p3113 is running CM 11 rom. both are rooted. i am trying to turn it on when it's off.

if i run the following via adb shell:

```
root@android:/ # echo +100 >/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm
```

i see the rtc alarm is set:

```
root@android:/ # cat /proc/driver/rtc
cat /proc/driver/rtc
rtc_time        : 05:05:11
rtc_date        : 2014-05-23
alrm_time       : 05:06:43
alrm_date       : 2014-05-23
alarm_IRQ       : yes
alrm_pending    : no
update IRQ enabled      : no
periodic IRQ enabled    : no
periodic IRQ frequency  : 1024
max user IRQ frequency  : 1024
24hr            : yes
trim/divider            : 0x00007fff
RTSR                    : 0x00000034
```

however, the device never wakes up when turned off.

what can i do to turn the device back on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whoa, did we go in the wrong direction. here's what we did instead:

1) first we needed to know high to low flow of the Android OS using the desk clock as an example:

```
. / Packages / apps / CameraRecorder.java (was desk clock app. we changed this) 
. / Frameworks / base / core / java / android / app / AlarmManager.java 
. / Frameworks / base / services / java / com / android / server / AlarmManagerService.java 
. / Frameworks / base / services / jni / com_android_server_AlarmManagerService.cpp 
. / Kernel / kernel / drivers / rtc / alarm-dev.c 
. / Kernel / kernel / include / linux / android_alarm.h 
. / Kernel / kernel / drivers / rtc / alarm.c 
. / Kernel / kernel / drivers / rtc / interface.c 
. / kernel / kernel/drivers/rtc/rtc-twl.c (we changed this driver to fit our Android device)
```

2) then cherry-pick the code from github (thankfully devs already did what we needed)

https://github.com/AriesVE-DevCon-TEAM/samsung-kernel-msm7x30
https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base

all this wouldn't have even been possible unless we had CM running on our 32 core server keeping compilation times down to 10-20 minutes.